# Bind input field not work

Tags: sapui5

I have a problem when I try to mapping my model in my view.
I have a view View that contains

```
    <form:SimpleForm
        minWidth="1024"
        maxContainerCols="2"
        editable="true"
        layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
        title="Dimensione prodotto"
        labelSpanL="3"
        labelSpanM="3"
        emptySpanL="4"
        emptySpanM="4"
        columnsL="1"
        columnsM="1"
        class="editableForm">

        <Label text="Codice" />
        <Input value="{elements/idCodProd/value}" id="idCodProd" />
        <Label text="Descrizione" />
        <Input value="{idDescProd/value}" id="idDescProd" />
        <Label text="Famiglia" />
        <Input value="{idFamiglia/value}" id="idFamiglia" />

    </form:SimpleForm>
```

and this model
(JSONModel)

```
{
    "elements":{
        "idCodProd":{
            "id":"idCodProd",
            "enabled":true,
            "required":true,
            "value":"123"
        },
        "idDescProd":{
            "id":"idDescProd",
            "enabled":true,
            "required":true
        },
        "idFamiglia":{
            "id":"idFamiglia",
            "lookup":"TAB_FAM",
            "enabled":true,
            "required":true
        }
    }
}
```

How can Ibind the value of idCodProd in the input??
I set the model to the view correctly but in the first input I not see "123"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solve my problem:
I replace `{elements/idCodProd/value}` with `{/elements/idCodProd/value}`

Comment: To explain this: If you use a path without leading "/" is is considered relative to the binding context of the parent. Since there is no binding context set on the Parent, this will not work. You can either bind the parent with form.bindElement("/"), which is not really a great idea since that is not a meaningful context, or bind the paths in an absolute way (which was your solution).